Is there a W(1)-hard paremeter for Knapsack?
I am currently working on a parameterized reduction from the Knapsack problem to demonstrate that a particular problem is non-FPT. Specifically, I hope to show that the Knapsack or Resource Constrained Shortest Path (RCSP) problem is W(1)-hard for the parameter k. In the RCSP context, k represents the number of different lengths, and in the Knapsack context, k represents the number of different values. I would appreciate it if there is a paper that shows these problems are W(1)-hard or a different problem similar to these that is shown to be W(1)-hard.
